# Reference "Product Name" set in Build Settings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, settings

Is there a way to reference the "Product Name" key set in Build Settings in my .m file (aside from the obvious parsing of the .plist)?  Basically, I would like to reference the "Product Name" in code so that when this key is changed it gets propagated in the .m file.  I rather not have to set it in Build Settings and then in code.  Thanks.

Comment: How would you reference it unless you open the plist file?

Comment: to clarify -- i was hoping to avoid opening & parsing the .plist file myself.  I guess the NSBundle class opens it indirectly (to your point).  The bundleIdentifier property is close.  Is there the product name property I am missing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but if you have a product name field you could access it as such.

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"Product Name: %@", [plistDict objectForKey:@"Product Name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```